# Replace empty space in array of string in spark scala

Tags: scala

I have a scenario where Array[String] has got empty space. When i apply replace it doesn't return proper result. What would be mistake in my implementation.

```
scala> val chk2 =Array("8.0","60.0","")
chk2: Array[String] = Array(8.0, 60.0, "")

scala> val chk3 = chk2.map(x => (x.replace("", "0")))
chk3: Array[String] = Array(080.000, 06000.000, 0)
```

Comment: I've removed the `apache-spark` tag since it is unrelated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` with pattern matching:

```
chk2.map{ case "" => "0"; case x => x }
// res2: Array[String] = Array(8.0, 60.0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks..it helped me to fix it.